# Validating an Email in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using the pattern:

```
var pattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
```

So when I submit/send an email to myself from my contact form to test out a bunch of different email combinations, everything has worked except for:

```
whatever@yahoo.com && whatever@google.com
```

I'm not entirely sure why those two aren't being included, but I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3629438

Comment: Are you sure you stripped all whitespace before you tested them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you miss some chars in your pattern,
you may find here an answer

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

there is a code which handles more chars that you forgot, and the comment above too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats going wrong with yours, but here's an email pattern I've used successfully.

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
```

Comment: Just tried yours, didn't receive any yahoo or google emails back when I tested it... :/

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```
 var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/gmi
```

final code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        Enter Your Email : <input type="tel" id="email">
        <button onclick="isvalid()">Try</button>
        <p id="res"></p>
      <script>
          var res = document.getElementById("res");
          var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/gmi
          function isvalid(){
              str = document.getElementById("email").value;
              if(patt.test(str))
                  res.innerHTML = "Email is Valid";
              else
                  res.innerHTML = "Email is InValid";
          }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't receive an email from test@yahoo.com nor test@google.com when usingthis

Comment: @Speakmore The test() method tests for a match in a string.
This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: if find whatever@yahoo.com return True else return false.you can try another email.

Comment: So this is what I currently have:    
    'function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$";
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };'

Comment: @Speakmore i updated my post.